# vkCreateImage returns VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED although supported

Tags: c++, vulkan

My Vulkan implementation returns `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` whenever i call `vkCreateImage`. I checked output of `vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties` as well as output of `vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties` and made sure that format of the image i'm creating (with regard to it's creation parameters) is supported.
I've successfully initialized a Vulkan instance and a logical device, so the problem must lie somewhere else.

The Vulkan Spec mentions no `VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` as a possible return value from `vkCreateImage`, which makes it more hard to uproot the problem.

The `VkImageCreateInfo` structure i push to `vkCreateImage` is as follows:

```
imageCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
imageCreateInfo.flags = VK_IMAGE_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
imageCreateInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
imageCreateInfo.extent.width = 1024;
imageCreateInfo.extent.height = 1024;
imageCreateInfo.extent.depth = 1;
imageCreateInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
imageCreateInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
imageCreateInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
imageCreateInfo.mipLevels = 0;
imageCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
imageCreateInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
imageCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
imageCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the specification:

> mipLevels must be greater than 0

So judging by Your code, providing 0 value for number of mip levels may be the reason (or one of the reasons) of failure.